# How to check 3D plots within reference path?

Tags: python, math, path, 3d, planning

For a drone competition, I have:

A- reference 3D trajectory (around 30 points or less)
B- tolerance from that ideal trajectory (say in cm or less)
C- experimental 3D points read from the drone's GPS (about 5000 points)

A bit like in:

RED: reference (A)
BLUE: experimental (C)
GREEN: "tolerance" (A+B, well not really, but you get the idea...)

[image: 3D path planning]

I'd like to know the best way to check that the "experimental 3D points" (C) all falls within the "reference 3D trajectory" (A) plus/minus the expected "tolerance" (B).

Closest matches I've found here is:

- [Finding out if a curve is inside or outside a boundary in python. X axis with different resolutions (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63174254/finding-out-if-a-curve-is-inside-or-outside-a-boundary-in-Python-x-axis-with-di)
- [Approximating data with a multi segment cubic bezier curve and a distance as well as a curvature contraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22556381/approximating-data-with-a-multi-segment-cubic-bezier-curve-and-a-distance-as-wel)
- [Fit Curve-Spline to 3D Point Cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64911820/fit-curve-spline-to-3D-point-cloud)
- [How to compare two 3D curves in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51730532/how-to-compare-two-3D-curves-in-Python)
- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980101/what's-the-best-method-to-compare-original-trajectory-with-two-compressed-trajec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980101/what%27s-the-best-method-to-compare-original-trajectory-with-two-compressed-trajec)

From github I've found something close:

- https://pypi.org/project/similaritymeasures/

Yet I'd like to be sure I can compare trajectories with different number of points ("reference" +/- "tolerance" provides a simplified "tunnel"). That difference of dataset is the main drawback, since the drone can stop, perhaps even go backward a little before resuming the race.

Maybe displaying the result using Mathpy and/or Payton as well.

While the timing is a factor, it would be nice to do some stats like the min/max deviation from the "reference 3D trajectory" (A).

Probably out of scope, but:

- https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281188521_Model_Predictive_Path-Following_Control_of_an_ARDrone_Quadrotor
- https://www.researchgate.net/publication/247935750_UAV_Motion_Estimation_using_Hybrid_Stereoscopic_Vision

Comment: Is the checking based on the cloud of points? Say, each point b in B (experimental) is is close enough to some point ?

Comment: "reference" (A) forms lines, with "tolerance" (B) it forms cylinders, "experimental" (C) is a path/track composed of several points. No "cloud" involved, (A) and (B) are precise, just that (C) can be not very straight.